# kdiff3 doen not show uft8

Tags: mercurial, utf-8, merge

I am using kdiff3 with TortoiseHg. 
When merging file in utf-8 encoding, kdiff3 show all non-latin text like

> "СЃРєР»Р°Рґ".

How I can fix this?

Comment: Is your question, How do I get KDiff3 to hide non-latin text?

Answer (score 21):

In Kdiff3

Main menu: `Settings` - `Configure Kdiff3` - `Regional settings` tab

Select "Unicode, 8 bit" in case of UTF8 without BOM or enable "Auto detect Unicode" in case of UTF8-BOM

[image]

Comment: I have no `Unicode, 8 bit(UTF-8)` in the File encoding for A combobox. What should I do?

Comment: It's the first choice in the combo (not respecting the alphabetical order).